# How can I access drawable resource of sherlock actionbar

Tags: android

Currently, sherlock actriobar is imported as project library.

I'm particular interested, in using 1 of the sherlock actionbar resources in my own project layout.

```
JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\drawable-xhdpi\abs__ab_bottom_solid_inverse_holo.9.png
```

In library project of sherlock actionbar, the resource file is being used as

### JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-e5c2d1c\library\res\values\abs__styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    ...
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_inverse_holo</item>
```

I was wondering, how I can refer to resource of sherlock actionbar?

In my own project layout file, I try

```
<FrameLayout
    android:background="?attr/backgroundSplit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
```

It doesn't work for me.

Is there anything I had missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
android:background="?attr/backgroundSplit"
```

use regular

```
android:background="@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_inverse_holo"
```

Alternatively, you can simply copy out the drawable and put a copy in your app's drawables (don't forget to rename it) so you stay immune to any changes of this drawable future version of the lib may bring.

Comment: Do you know why "?attr/backgroundSplit" doesn't work? One of the workaround I can come out with, is defines the following in my own style (themes.xml) `<item name="widgetActionBarBackground">@drawable/abs__ab_bottom_solid_inverse_holo</item>`